# Ordinal regression validation in R

Tags: r, regression, assumptions, validation, ordered-logit

I have constructed an ordinal logistic regression model in `R` using `lrm` or `polr` function.
I have checked the prediction power by checking the **Pseudo R square** as one of the indexes to check the model.

I'm still a bit confused in terms of which function and which direction I should look into to make sure my model follow those assumptions, to which i can make inference from the model.